# TFS: cannot build my app, CS0042: Unexpected error creating debug information file. Access is denied.

Tags: tfs

I am trying to deploy my MVC app, but in the TFS build I get this error message;

CSC : fatal error CS0042: Unexpected error creating debug information file 'c:\Builds\2\STAS\STAS\Sources\Documents and Settings\jyothisrinivasa\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\STAS\STAS\obj\Debug\STAS.PDB' -- 'c:\Builds\2\STAS\STAS\Sources\Documents and Settings\jyothisrinivasa\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\STAS\STAS\obj\Debug\STAS.pdb: Access is denied.

I have excluded the Debug directory from my application, so why am I getting this?

Comment: It's possible you have a read-only version already in that location.  Have you looked?

Comment: There is something going on with this. CSC creates pdb files. If the build completes successfully, they are left writable. But in some cases, probably build failures, they are left read-only. This causes future builds to fail b/c a read-only file exists at the target path. I think it's a bug of sorts because it renders the build process not ACID (because it's not isolated b/c it's not repeatable), but I can't narrow in on the problem further just yet. Extra lines of code would have to be added to the build to first clean up a possible previous failed run.

Comment: Comment from a deleted answer by a TFS MVP (ex MSFT DevOps): `Its possible that Visual Studio is holding a lock on that file. Try closing all instances of Visual Studio and re-opening them.

Alternatively, others have had success with changing the project to 'Release' mode then back to 'Debug' mode.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably still checked into TFS.

Answer (score 4):

Delete the obj folder! It should work.

Comment: The obj folder seems to be included in TFS